# javascript child function pass the return to the parent function return

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, callback

i want to pass the return from a "child" (i don't know the correct term) function to the return in the parent function... how is the correct way to do this? check_data() isn't returning true or false

```
function check_data(type,field){
    var chkvalue = $(field).val();
    $.post("mods/ajax.fieldchk.php", {
        chkvalue: chkvalue,
        type: type
    },
    function(result){
        if(result==0){
            $(field).css({'background-color': '#faa', 'border': '1px solid #f00'});
            return false;
        }else if(result==1){
            $(field).css({'background-color': '#afa', 'border': '1px solid #0f0'});
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

thnx

Comment: You can't return from an asynchronous action such as `$.post()`. Read the topics above to learn about working with callbacks and Deferred objects.

Comment: $.post is an asynchronous function by default, so your check_data function will exit before your expecting it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `$.post` is an asynchronous function you can't use it to return data on check_data. However you can pass some callback and execute with `true/false` argument.

Something like this:

```
function check_data(type,field,callback){
    var chkvalue = $(field).val();
    $.post("mods/ajax.fieldchk.php", {
        chkvalue: chkvalue,
        type: type
    },
    function(result){
        if(result==0){
            $(field).css({'background-color': '#faa', 'border': '1px solid #f00'});
            callback(true);
        }else if(result==1){
            $(field).css({'background-color': '#afa', 'border': '1px solid #0f0'});
            callback(false);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I think it'd be kind of you to provide a sample callback function.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I would if I knew what he is trying to achieve